# Question on Uniform Continuity

Tags: analysis, metric-spaces, continuity

Is it generally true that all uniformly continuous bijections $f: X \to Y$, where $X$ and $Y$ are metric spaces, have uniformly continuous inverses? If not, then what would be a counterexample, and is there another condition which does ensure it? Thanks.

Comment: $\arctan : \mathbb R \to (-\pi/2, \pi/2)$ is a uniformly continuous bijection but $\tan$ is not.

Comment: Alright. I suppose that should've been a pretty obvious one. Is there something stronger than uniform continuity which would do it?

Comment: If $X$ is compact. I suspect there's a weaker condition.